# Очень много одиночных запросов на index странице. Как исправить?

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть стандартная index страница с таблицей. Там может быть выведено много данных из связанных таблиц, например:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'responsible_id',
    'value' => function($model) {
        return $model->responsible->name ?? '';
    },
    'filter' => $data['headTypes']
],
[
    'attribute' => 'owner_id',
    'value' => function($model) {
        return $model->owner->name ?? '';
    },
    'filter' => $data['headTypes']
],
```

При таком варианте в профайлере вижу очень много запросов по типу:

```
SELECT * FROM "directory"."head_type" o WHERE "id"=1
SELECT * FROM "directory"."head_type" r WHERE "id"=1
SELECT * FROM "directory"."head_type" m WHERE "id"=2
SELECT * FROM "directory"."head_type" n WHERE "id"=3
SELECT * FROM "directory"."head_type" i WHERE "id"=1
SELECT * FROM "directory"."head_type" d WHERE "id"=2
```

Это норма? Или как-то можно сделать правильное что-то, что я не знаю?

---

метод index

```
 public function actionIndex() {
        $searchModel = new ElementSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $headTypes = HeadType::find()->select(['id', 'name'])->asArray()->all();
    
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'data' => ['headTypes' => $headTypes]
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Покажи контроллер или метод, в котором запрос выполняется.

Comment: @fedornabilkin он самый обычный... добавил. но ничем не примечательный... вот  модель поиска да...там много `joinWith` типа `->joinWith('owner o')`, `->joinWith('organization org')` и т.д.

Comment: Так именно модель поиска и нужна. Там же основной запрос формируется. Добавляй все, инфа лишней не бывает.

Comment: охохох.. сложно. потому что буду светить данные, которые нельзя светить)) Но на самом деле там кроме выборки из основной модели и десятка `joinWith` ничего нет. И дальше фильтрация через `andFilterWhere` еще около 20-ти полей и всё

Comment: Чтоб не светить данные, держи их в конфиге или в енвах.

Comment: @fedornabilkin держать данные в конфиге или в енвах чтобы не светить на стаке? :))) Я конечно мог придумать липовые имена, конечно на всё))

Comment: Нет, не только для стака. Это стандартная практика, не хардкодить данные доступов и прочее в файле. Хотя бы только потому, что код проекта в репозитории.

Comment: Вам нужно подробнее узнать о жадной и ленивой загрузки https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/834/relational-query-lazy-loading-and-eager-loading-in-yii-2-0

Comment: `joinWith` по сути создаст запрос вида `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id IN (...)`, что тоже не зер гут т.к многие СУБД этот запрос нагружает больше чем правильно собранный запрос с прямым `JOIN`. Мой совет - либо напишите в `searchModel` обычный `Query` с отлаженным запросом где через `JOIN` собраны все необходимые поля. Вся разница `Query` от `Model` в том, что при выводе Вы будете работать не с `Object`, а с `array`. Либо на стороне `БД` создайте `view` в которой будут уже собраны через тот же запрос все необходимые поля. На ее основе сгенерируйте `model` такую же как от обычной таблицы.

Comment: Единственный минус `view` на стороне `БД` - не все `БД` хорошо с ними работают при больших объемах данных. Например этим страдает `postgresql`.